# Const array in .hpp and .cpp file

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files

In my .hpp file I have

```
extern const double MY_CONST[44];
```

and in my .cpp file I have

```
const double MY_CONST[44];
```

and I get something like this:

```
error: uninitialized const 'MY_CONST' [-fpermissive]
```

Could you please tell me where the error is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `const` object must be initialized. You can declare them `extern`, but you must assign them. You may like to do:

```
const double MY_CONST[44] ={0};
```

To default initialize them all to zero. But that doesn't mean anything, since they are const (and will always have value `0`).